# What does conceptually this integration do in R?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, bayesian

Long ago (20+ years ago), I had this knowledge that integration is used to compute areas under functions or volumes of ***n-dimensional*** objects.

But now, I want to specifically know what exactly the ***integration below*** (*written in R code*) is doing in a conceptually deep manner?

```
H1 = integrate(function(delta) dcauchy(delta, 0, sqrt(2)/2) * dt(2.6, 98, delta*sqrt(20)), -Inf, Inf)[[1]]
## 0.06127036
```

To be clear, the function `dcauchy(...)` looks like the following:

[image]

And the function `dt(...)` looks like the following:

[image]

Comment: It appears to be integrating a certain function on the interval $-\infty$ to $\infty$.  Since we don't know what dcauchy or dt represent, I don't see how you can expect us to know anything conceptually deep about it.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, please let me edit my question than and show some graphs. Please give me a moment.

Comment: @RobertIsrael, please see my edited question.

Comment: I think you need to tell us exactly what these things do, not just give graphs.

Comment: @SeanRoberson, I tagged the question as being related to probability distribution hoping colleagues with that background could probably respond.

Comment: OK, so it's integrating the product of these functions.  Apparently you consider them to be probability densities.  If $f$ and $g$ are probability densities for independent random variables $X$ and $Y$, then the density for $Z = X-Y$ at $z$ is $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x) g(x-z)\; dx$, so maybe this is finding the density of $X-Y$ at $0$.